# How rotate the 3D view irrespective to the global Z axis using keyboard?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I have set the "orbit style" setting to *"trackball"* but it only works when I use the middle mouse button to rotate the view.

The keyboard shortcut does not seems to honor the "orbit style=trackball" setting as numpad 4 / numpad 6 still uses the "turntable" style rotation, and rotate about the global Z axis.

I need to use the keyboard for rotation because I would like to constrain my 3D view rotation to one axis (vertical/horizontal only).

For example, if I

1. set orbit style to trackball
2. hit numpad 7 to align the 3D view to Top View
3. drag middle mouse button left/right

[image]

The 3D view will rotate horizontally as desired, however if I hit numpad 4 / numpad 6 instead, it "roll" along the global Z axis

[image]

I want to have the same behavior as mouse using keyboard.

I am using Blender 2.76a.

Answer (score 2):

<s>You can roll the view with Shift + Numpad 4 and Shift + Numpad 6.</s>

Edit: Oops. <s>This only works in turntable mode.</s> I misunderstood the question. (Still investigating.)

Edit 2: Sorry. I couldn't figure it out. The best I can offer is this workaround:

Make the model a child of an empty, then rotate the empty 90º on the X axis. From there, you can view the top with Numpad 1 and orbit latitudinally with respect to the object with Numpad 4 and Numpad 6. Once you're done, you can delete the empty and the object will return to its pre-parented orientation.

This is not ideal because it might mess with the mechanics of an armature or other constraints or modifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion. The workaround does the job but it doesn't really solve the problem of moving the view in trackball style. Therefore I just up voted your answer but I will not mark this as the accepted answer.